# How to publish an event to an IObservable<T>

Tags: rx.net

So say I have the following class:

```
public class User
{
    public IObservable<IEvent> Events { get; }

    public User(Guid id, string username, string password) => Events = Observable.Return(new UserCreated(id, username, password));

    public void ChangeUsername(string username)
    {
        // TODO: Append a ChangeUsername event to the sequence of events
    }
}
```

How would I append a ChangeUsername (which implemented IEvent) to my event sequence? And have my subscribers also be notified that the ChangeUsername event has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it, you can't. `Events` is bound to the result of `Observable.Return` which returns one value and then completes. No more values.

Probably the easiest way to get started is with a `Subject`:

```
public class User
{
    private readonly Subject<IEvent> _subject = new Subject<IEvent>();
    public IObservable<IEvent> Events => _subject;

    public User(Guid id, string username, string password) => _subject.OnNext(new UserCreated(id, username, password));

    public void ChangeUsername(string username)
    {
        _subject.OnNext(new ChangeUserName(username));
    }
}

public interface IEvent
{}

public class ChangeUserName : IEvent
{
    public ChangeUserName(string userName) {}
}

public class UserCreated : IEvent
{
    public UserCreated(Guid id, string userName, string password){}
}
```